# How to stop animation in a particular slide not on the master slide PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I have a presentation, and I want all the slides to have animations in them (Except view). Therefore, I did animation on the master slide. However, it turns out that there is no way that I may suppress animation on a particular slide.

Can I stop animation on a particular slide if I have my master slide been animated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to have two master styles available. In this example, I have one called "Title and Content - Animated" and one called "Title and Content - Not Animated". On the normal slide editing view, right-click the slide and choose "Layout" - then you can apply the layout you want.

I made this by copying and pasting the slide layout I already had (in the master view) and then removing the animation.

As far as I know, this is the only way to have one or more slides not-animated in a presentation where the master has animation built-in:

[image: Choosing a layout]

Comment: I created 2 masters slides, one with automation and another without one. Therefore, I tried your trick but did not work for me. Is there something I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some tricks need to be done.

1. Go to the Animations tab
2. Click on the Animation Pane
   [image]
3. On the side of the right-hand side of the powerpoint presentation, you will see 
   [image]
4. Press on the arrow key and press on "Copy effects to Slide"
5. Remove the animation (either all or one by one)